# No Wi-Fi Connection

Tags: networking

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 for the first time on my desktop computer. I don't have access to Ethernet so WiFi is my only option, I do have Tp-Link Archer T9E installed on it but after Ubuntu finished installing, I cant figure out how to connect to the WiFi. How do I install the driver? It is BSM4360.

Thank you,
Sal

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and `rfkill list all`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your settings and find Network settings and turn your wireless ON. It should automaticly install driver needed.